# Analizar log con python

Tags: log

Soy nuevo en el mundo python, quisiera me ayuden a poder realizar el siguiente análisis sobre un log formato txt (adjunto -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pobj8Ai-26Wr5ACQ7t6IF7JWSPf6ezSZ/view?usp=sharing).

Necesito leer dicho log y extraer las lineas, primero la linea que contiene CLIENT (ejemplo: MUN1MSC                           5   M3UA        CLIENT ), luego los datos referidos esta linea "CLIENT" (cada linea client tiene conexión a  5 puntos  del 0 al 5 (son los ASSOC. IND )), o sea, saber si alguno de estos servicio  esta SCTP-DOWN (ejemplp: 0    BCXU-2    ---     HUAWEI           SCTP-DOWN ) y agrupar en una lista estos datos (tanto la linea CLIENT y sus correspondientes servicios caidos, o sea, las lineas SCTP-DOWN encontradas) y asi sucesivamente sobre los  demas CLIENT.
De modo de obtener una lista donde cada elemento sea a su vez una lista que contanga como elementos las lineas CLIENT y sus servicios si estuvieran caidos (SCTP-DOWN).
La idea es poder identificar rapidamente  los servicios  caidos de cada CLIENT y luego volcarlo a un txt, excel por ejemplo.

Logre realizar los siguiente:

```
fail = []
caido = 'SCTP-DOWN'
mme = "CLIENT"
with open ("zoyi.txt") as f:
   lineas = f.read().split("ASSOCIATION SET NAME") 
   for i in range(len(lineas)): 
   
       completo = lineas[i]
       cortado = completo.splitlines() 
       for x in range(len(cortado)):
           cortadito = cortado[x] 
       
           if mme in cortadito or caido in cortadito:
           
               fail.append(cortadito)
print('\n'.join(fail))
```

Y obtengo lo siguiente:

> ```
> MUN1MSC                           5   M3UA        CLIENT
>       0    BCXU-2    ---     HUAWEI           SCTP-DOWN           
>       2    BCXU-2    ---     HUAWEI           SCTP-DOWN           
>       4    BCXU-2    ---     HUAWEI           SCTP-DOWN            BEL1MSC                           6   M3UA        CLIENT CLI1MSC      
> 7   M3UA        CLIENT
>       0    BCXU-2    ---     HUAWEI           SCTP-DOWN           
>       2    BCXU-2    ---     HUAWEI           SCTP-DOWN           
>       4    BCXU-2    ---     HUAWEI           SCTP-DOWN
> ```

Si  bien el código me sirvió, quisiera su expertise para hacerlo mas eficiente,  trabajo mucho con este tipo/formato de log (información línea por línea) y me cuesta poder analizarlos, en el sentido que necesito leer una línea (A) y saber si las líneas siguientes que dependen de (A) a su vez cumplen o no otros requisitos y extraerlos.

Espero a ver sido claro en mi explicación y desde ya muchas gracias a todos.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es una pregunta basada en opiniones, porque has podido resolver el problema y la petición de sugerencias en el sitio son tomadas como tal.

Sin embargo, si te sirve, también puedes procesarlo en formato diccionario que naturalmente se puede convertir a `JSON` y de esta forma es más fácil de procesar para otro sistema o librería de muestra de datos, o bien servirlo por medio de API.

```
fail = []
i = -1
with open ("stack055.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.split() # Se convierte la linea en lista de palabras
        if 'CLIENT' in data:
            fail.append({'CLIENT':data[0], 'CLID':data[1], 'DOWN':[]})
            i += 1
            continue
        if "SCTP-DOWN" in data:
            fail[i]['DOWN'].append(f'{data[0]},{data[1]},{data[3]}')
print(fail)
```

Salida:

```
[
    {
        'CLIENT': 'MUN1MSC', 
        'CLID': '5',
        'DOWN': ['0,BCXU-2,HUAWEI', '2,BCXU-2,HUAWEI', '4,BCXU-2,HUAWEI']
    }, 
    {
        'CLIENT': 'BEL1MSC', 
        'CLID': '6',
        'DOWN': []
    }, 
    {
       'CLIENT': 'CLI1MSC', 
       'CLID': '7',
       'DOWN': ['0,BCXU-2,HUAWEI', '2,BCXU-2,HUAWEI', '4,BCXU-2,HUAWEI']
    }
]
```

Comment: Excelente solución aeportugal, voy a seguir esta propuesta de json es muy potente.Ahora consulto por la visualización del resultado, mi intención es verlo en formato fila/columnas, debería convertirlo a csv? o hay otra forma mas optima de hacerlo? muchas gracias desde ya... saludos

Comment: consulta al respecto del formato json, estuve investigando/probando con la solución brindada por @aeportugal que me parece mucho mas practica, pero me quedan dudas en cuanto al formato de salida, o sea,  es una lista que contiene diccionarios y el formato json seria un diccionario que puede contener  listas de objetos, o no importa esto? porque no logro armar con el formato "salida" un dataframe para poder leerlo como filas/columnas, entonces es necesario armar la salida como json o no hay inconvenientes en seguir el  formato como lista que contiene diccionarios? desde ya gracias